How to check spark job on Amazon EMR console by job submit with lvy
I can successfully submit spark job through Apache livy to Amazon EMR.
But I did not see any steps on Amazon EMR console.
Though my spark job was completed and success, I could only check job state from livy rest api.
How Amazon EMR console reflect the spark job?
Traditionally, I submit job from Amazon EMR api, then I can see the steps and instances running in console.
Now, I created Amazon EMR cluster with Livy, submit job from livy rest api, nothing display on Amazon EMR console.
Who knows why? Does livy created job behind Amazon EMR console?
Explain how livy working in Amazon EMR service.
